# SQL INNER JOIN with MULTIPLE CONDITION in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have the following table.

table **cards**

```
------------------------------------
| card_no          | approval_code |
------------------------------------
| 999999xxxxxx1234 | 111111        |
 ----------------------------------
| 888888xxxxxx5678 | 222222        |
------------------------------------
| 777777xxxxxx9012 | 333333        |
 -----------------------------------
| 666666xxxxxx3456 | 444444        |
 -----------------------------------
```

table **transactions**

```
---------------------------------------------
| trans_id | pan   | approval code  | amount |
---------------------------------------------
| A1       | 9012  | 333333         |     9.9|
----------------------------------------------
| A2       | 9012  | 333333         |    10.0|
----------------------------------------------
| B1       | 1233  | 111111         |    11.0|
----------------------------------------------
| B2       | 1234  | 111111         |    12.0|
----------------------------------------------
| C1       | 5678  | 222222         |    13.0|
----------------------------------------------
| C2       | 5678  | 444444         |    13.0|
----------------------------------------------
```

My output is to display 3 types of output.
1st output is to display matched data and 2nd output is to display unmatched data from cards table and 3rd output is to display unmatched data from transactions table. the following are my codes. transaction table only store pan (last 4 digit from card_no) therefore i need to substr to get the last 4 digit.

for matched data:

```
$query = $this->db->select (array(
'c.card_no', 'c.approval_code',
't.trans_id','t.pan','t.approval_code','amount'
),false)
-> join('transactions t','t.approval_code = c.approval_code','inner')
-> join('transactions t','t.pan = substr(c.card_no,12)','inner')
-> get('cards c');
```

for unmatched data from cards table;

```
$query = $this->db->select (array(
'c.card_no', 'c.approval_code',
't.trans_id','t.pan','t.approval_code','amount'
),false)
-> join('transactions t','t.approval_code != c.approval_code','inner')
-> join('transactions t','t.pan != substr(c.card_no,12)','inner')
-> where ('t.approval_code' IS NULL,NULL,FALSE)
-> where ('t.pan' IS NULL,NULL,FALSE)
-> get('cards c');
```

for unmatched data from transactions table;

```
$query = $this->db->select (array(
'c.card_no', 'c.approval_code',
't.trans_id','t.pan','t.approval_code','amount'
),false)
-> join('cards c','t.approval_code = c.approval_code','inner')
-> join('cards c','t.pan != substr(c.card_no,12)','inner')
-> where ('c.approval_code' IS NULL,NULL,FALSE)
-> where ('c.card_no' IS NULL,NULL,FALSE)
-> get('cards c');
```

Both seems not working.. hmmmm
my expected outputs are:

output **matched data**

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| card_no          | approval_code | trans_id | amount |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 999999xxxxxx1234 | 111111        | B2       | 12.0   |
 -------------------------------------------------------
| 888888xxxxxx5678 | 222222        | C1       | 13.0   |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 777777xxxxxx9012 | 333333        | A1       | 9.9    |
 -------------------------------------------------------
| 777777xxxxxx9012 | 333333        | A2       | 10.0   |
 -------------------------------------------------------
```

output **unmatched data from table cards**

```
------------------------------------
| card_no          | approval_code |
------------------------------------
| 666666xxxxxx3456 | 444444        |
 -----------------------------------
```

output **unmatched data from table transactions**

```
---------------------------------------------
| trans_id | pan   | approval code  | amount |
---------------------------------------------
| B1       | 1233  | 111111         |    11.0|
----------------------------------------------
| C2       | 5678  | 444444         |    13.0|
----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: to match on `IS NULL` you'd need `left` joins, not `inner` right?

Comment: I'm still stuck.. tried both .. i still didnt get the result that i want.. a little help please.. thanks

Comment: I got unmatched data from transactions but cannot get from cards..

Answer (score 0):

To get unmatched data from `cards` table replace `join` by `right join`. And for unmatched data from `transactions` table replace `join` by `left join` in respective queries.

Comment: I tried but still didnt get the matched and unmatched data correctly.